# Cannot break out of a Task with the use of boolean flags - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, loops, task

I have a class `AcquisitionWriter` that writes received data to a file periodically. It is used by another class `ClientClass` which has a `Reset` method that should stop current acquisition and overwrite the file, while keeping recording from then on. This is done by calling `writer.FinishSection()` followed by `writer.OpenFile(filename)` and `writer.Start()`.

The problem is: `FinishSection` does not seem to stop writing actions to keep going, so when I call `OpenFile(filename)`, the file is already open.

I have tried to make the boolean flags `volatile`, but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I suspect either the `GoOnWritingFrames` Task keeps running even when it's supposed to have stopped, or the File is not being properly closed, or perhaps something else.

```
internal class ClientClass
{
    AcquisitionWriter _writer = new AcquisitionWriter();



    protected override void Start()
    {
        _writer.OpenFile();
        _writer.StartRecordingSession();
    }

    protected override void Pause()
    {
        _writer.EndRecordingSession();
    }

    protected override void Reset()   
    {
        /// HERE IS THE PROBLEM:
        /// EndRecordingSession seems not to be enough to prevent 
        /// _writer.GoOnRecordingFrames() to keep going,
        /// so "OpenFile()" gives IOError because the file is still/already open

        _writer.EndRecordingSession();
        _writer.OpenFile();
        _writer.StartRecordingSession();
    }

    protected override void Finish()
    {
        _writer.EndRecordingSession();
    }




    public void ProcessarFrame(object sender, Frame frame)
    {            
        _writer.AdicionarFrame(frame);
    }

}



public class AcquisitionWriter
{
    private string _file_path = SomewhereElse.getFilePath();


    Queue<Frame> _frames = new Queue<Frame>();
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    // two flags to sinalize a new file cannot (yet) be open
    private volatile bool _recording = false;
    private volatile bool _finishing_recording = false;




    public void OpenFile()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(_file_path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            var headerBytes = SomewhereElse.getHeaderBytes();
            writer.Write(headerBytes);

            writer.Write(SomewhereElse.GROUP_SEPARATOR);
        }
    }



    public void StartRecordingSession()
    {
        ConfigureRecordingSession();

        _recording = true;

        Task.Run(() => GoOnRecordingFrames());
    }


    private void ConfigureRecordingSession()
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(_file_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            int elapsed = Convert.ToInt32((DateTime.UtcNow - SomewhereElse.StartTime).TotalMilliseconds);
            writer.Write(elapsed);

            var ActiveIndices = SomewhereElse.getActiveIndices();

            byte numberOfActiveSensors = (byte)(ActiveIndices.Count());
            writer.Write(numberOfActiveSensors);

            byte[] indicesOfActiveChannels = ActiveIndices.Select(i => Convert.ToByte(i))
                                                          .ToArray();
            writer.Write(indicesOfActiveChannels);
        }
    }


    private void GoOnRecordingFrames()
    {
        bool shouldContinue = true;

        while (shouldContinue)
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_file_path, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
            {
                while (_frames.Count > 0)
                {
                    Frame frame;
                    lock (_lockObj)
                    {
                        frame = _frames.Dequeue();
                    }
                    writer.Write(frame.Serialize());
                }

                if (!_recording)
                {
                    writer.Write(SomewhereElse.END_SEPARATOR); // need to write this only upon exit
                    _finishing_recording = true;
                    shouldContinue = false;
                }
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        _finishing_recording = false;
    }



    public void AddFrame(Frame frame)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            _frames.Enqueue(frame);
        }
    }


    public void EndRecordingSession()
    {
        _recording = false;

        while (_finishing_recording) 
        {
            ;
        }

        int x = 0;
    }



    public bool Recording
    {
        get { return _recording; }
    }


}
```

Comment: You might need to close the file before you open it again.

Comment: @user1666620 I am using the `using` clause everywhere I open the file for creation/writing, so I guess it is being closed automatically afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

A boolean will not "magically" end an operation, Read/Writes are synchronous, so unless an exception breaks it, the operation will continue until it has been finished.

So, the easiest way to solve your problem is to save a reference of the open stream and if you must cancel the operation while it's still running, just close and dispose it, it will break the execution (remember to trap the exception) and the file will be ready to be opened.

Comment: I'm (still) getting IOError saying "the file is being used by another process"... :(

Comment: Then or you didn't call your function to abort the operation or another instance is trying to open the file. When the exception is risen, take a look at the Threads window and look at which code is in execution, I'm very sure some of the threads will still have the file open

Comment: Well, looks like we're going somewhere :) : there are two instances of `GoOnRecordingFrames` method, where should only be one. This happened, I suspect, after I executed (via GUI button) the `Reset` command twice. Still there should be only one instance of it, at most. Any suggestion?

Comment: put a breakpoint atop of GoOnRecordingFrames and check where it's called from

Comment: Looks like it's called from the button click as I thought - and it's the right way by the way. The problem is that it's not being _terminated_ as I thought it would...

Answer (score 0):

The right answer for me was to do the following:

1. Use the Task Cancellation pattern, so that instead of:

   ```
   Task.Run(() => GoOnRecordingFrames());
   ```

   I have:

   ```
   _cancellation_token_source = new CancellationTokenSource();
   _cancellation_token = _cancellation_token_source.Token;
   _task = new Task(GoOnRecordingFrames, _cancellation_token);
   _task.Start();
   ```
2. Instead of setting a flag to break out of the loop, now I have a token cancellation **followed by a `Task.Wait`** so that the file is always closed by the task *before* it is open again for overwriting:

   ```
   public void EndRecordingSession()
   {
       if (_cancellation_token_source != null)
           _cancellation_token_source.Cancel();

       if (_task != null && _task.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
           _task.Wait();
   }
   ```
3. Handle the cancellation inside the loop:

   ```
   private void GoOnRecordingFrames()
   {
       bool continuar = true;

       while (continuar)
       {
           using (var stream = new FileStream(CaminhoArquivo, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write))
           using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
           {
               while (_frames.Count > 0)
               {
                   Frame frame;
                   lock (_lockObj)
                   {
                       frame = _frames.Dequeue();
                   }
                   writer.Write(frame.Serializar());
               }

               ////// Handling Cancellation using the Token!
               if (_cancellation_token.IsCancellationRequested)
               {
                   writer.Write(Separadores.END_SEPARATOR);
                   continuar = false;
               }
           }

           Thread.Sleep(100);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is not proper cooperative cancellation. Cooperative cancellation is when (in addition to what you've done) you pass your `CancellationToken` as an argument to `GoOnRecordingFrames` and check it periodically (inside `GoOnRecordingFrames`) via `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`, at points where it is safe to break the operation. You'll need to handle the resulting `TaskCanceledException` too. Also heads up: prepare for a torrent of "do not use `Task.Start` and `Task.Wait`" comments.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy you're right, and by the way I forgot to add that part to my answer. I have a field for the cancellation token (ugly!), but cancellation in some way being handled inside the method (see my update).